# Handling php object with number and string properties

Tags: php, object, joomla

When creating a custom field type for Joomla, $this->value contains something like the code below (from print_r):

```
JObject Object
(
    [_errors:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 5
)
```

I'm interested in retrieving the values in the numbered properties. I can cast the object to an array, loop through it, and retrieve the values from the numeric keys, but it seems clumsy.

Is there some smart method to handle this object?

Comment: _errors already is an array, which you can see from the print_r output. Conventional wisdom would suggest if you're supposed to access those errors there'll be a public getErrors method (or similar) available. Don't know Joomla so can't speculate further

Comment: Indeed there is: http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JObject::getErrors

Comment: Great, Clive, but as I said, I'm interested in the other data in the object, not the empty errors-array. I can not see there is any methods for retrieving this: http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JObject.html

Comment: Apologies, I parsed the print_r output wrongly. You'd hope they've made it enumerable - have you tried a foreach over the object itself?

Comment: Thanks, I tried just looping over the object now, and that returns only the numbered values, so it's a lot better that casting it first. Still: is it possible to get an array from this without looping over the object?

Comment: Not as such - whether you do it manually or there's a built-in method to help either way is going to be enumerating the object and copying the values into that array. I can't imagine the language itself having a shortcut for this (definitely never come across one), as enumerating is the logical equivalent, just with less CPU time

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the core Joomla JObject class, you can set and get variables like so:

```
$myObject->set('myProperty', $myValue);

$value = $myObject->get('myProperty');
```

Whatever you put into the set method (array, object, string) is what will be returned by the get method.

Answer (score 0):

what about deleting the first property?

I thing that this should work:

Say your object is a.

unset($a->_errors:protected);

Comment: The thing is, the object is protected, meaning it's accessible only inside the object, and in subclasses of the object, so I dont really have access to delete it... ( When I cast it to an array, it's converted to an index like like *_errors, which I find weird, but might be the object implementation? )